# Push src files only

Tags: java, git, repository

I want to push my Project to my Remote Repo but it creates it in the following Way

```
- GameAlerts
  - src/org/xendev
    > Main.java
  > README.md
```

instead, I want it to do it the following

```
- src/org/xenodev
    > Main.java
> README.md
```

where would I change this in Eclipse without using the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to add all the files present in src folder. Then do

git add src/

Comment: will this change when I commit future file changes or do I have to do it every time before I commit and push?

Answer (score 0):

Open git bash in your workspace which is `GameAlerts`.

```
cd src
```

Then commit and push all required folders which are

```
- src/org/xenodev
    > Main.java
```

Add README.md file to your repo.

Comment: is there a way to do it without the command line? like a setting in Eclipse or something

Comment: You can try using GIT GUI, Source Tree etc.

Comment: hm I would like to have all done in eclipse I got it to work once but that is some time ago...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Wf4FDDG this is how it looks when i do the first push

Comment: Are you tryna select src folder and push?

Comment: yes i am trying to push everything in the project folder without actually pushing the project folder with it